# Could not connect to ibm WML

Tags: ibm-cloud, wml

I am trying to do follow the ibm tutorial for object detection (https://cloud-annotations.github.io/training/object-detection/wml/) and i have a problem when I try to connect to the machine. Here are the credentials

```
{
 "apikey": "kIlCEVrah4Yi2Jexs4f6ryxtXK_UmlRRYbEHFDZPj3-U",
 "iam_apikey_description": "Auto generated apikey during resource-key operation for 
  Instance - crn:v1:bluemix:public:pm-20:eu- 
     gb:a/ba2f381a117d49a8898e3b9d244488cc:07c9e765-ab56-4303-a02d-ff487a394db0::",
  "iam_apikey_name": "auto-generated-apikey-0cb1a7b2-7037-45d8-9221-73116bf42f7b",
  "iam_role_crn": "crn:v1:bluemix:public:iam::::serviceRole:Writer",
  "iam_serviceid_crn": "crn:v1:bluemix:public:iam- 
               identity::a/ba2f381a117d49a8898e3b9d244488cc::serviceid:ServiceId- 
                                                 6f725bc1-f6d1-4a62-a7da-d8701494ad1e",
  "instance_id": "07c9e765-ab56-4303-a02d-ff487a394dba",
  "password": "0fda17b6-5b97-4cf3-ba69-ed355555b45a",
  "url": "https://eu-gb.ml.cloud.ibm.com",
  "username": "0cb1a7b2-7037-45d8-9221-73116bf42f7a"
}
```

and when i paste the username / password and instance_id i get the next error:

```
Status code: 404, body: {"trace":2894125269067430410,"errors":
    [{"code":"not_found","message":"User with given credentials not found.","target":
                                   {"type":"field","name":"token"},"moreInfo":null}]}
```

Any help would be awesome! Thank you!

Comment: You really shouldn't share your service credentials in a public forum.

Answer (score 0):

If you are following the instructions in the link you provided, then you are have most likely taken the wrong `instance_id` or not specified the `url` in the connection.

Your service credentials are showing `https://eu-gb.ml.cloud.ibm.com` which will be running on the UK hosted servers, which I am guessing will not be the default.